# Facebook Graph request can't retrieve email in iOS 9.2 - xCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

after the user signed up with Facebook, I'd like to retrieve some more information about the Facebook user. However, I'm only able to get id and name while apparently the email returns nil. This is my code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse
import MessageUI
import QuartzCore
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4
import FBSDKCoreKit
import Bolts
import FBSDKLoginKit

class FacebookCompleteSignUpController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler( {
            (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)

            } else if let result = result {
                print(result["first_name"])
                print(result["email"])

                do {
                    try PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
                } catch let ex {
                    print(ex)
                }
            }
        })   
    }
}
```

If anybody knows how to fix that it would be great if you could let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following could be a reason :

```
email

Provides access to the person's primary email address via the email property on the user object.

Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply with both Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.

Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.

Review
Your app may use this permission without review from Facebook.
```

Please try to access the same information with the Graph API explorer and see if you are getting email id of the user : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: I cannot get it from the Graph API either. The error it reports is : 
    The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user     grants the 'email' permission.

Comment: Even though, here in my Facebook App Review it says I do have the permission: [screenshot](http://s12.postimg.org/j5yhdgoql/Screen_Shot_2016_02_13_at_12_37_48_AM.png)

Comment: @GiulioColleluori : That's what the 3rd line in my comment says -  The user can decide whether or not to disclose his email. If the user decides not to share the email, you won't receive it. If the email is a must for your app, you'll have to prompt the user again with another window to type in the email. That's the way we implemented it for our app. You'll have to map the email id to the user_id you received from facebook.